# Database SQL order by value in column field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a WordPress blog with obviously a WordPress database.

Database name: `wordpress`

The two tables communicating are `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta`.

The table `usermeta` has columns `user_id`, `meta_key`, and `meta_value`.

```
user_id   meta_key          usermeta

1         name              mark
1         userurl           mark.com
1         points            8

2         name              luke
2         userurl           luke.com
2         points            4

2         name              frank
2         userurl           frank.com
2         points            6
```

I would display the data on a specific page like this and ordered by points value desc:

```
Name: Mark
User Blog: mark.com
points: 8

Name: Frank
User Blog: mark.com
points: 6

Name: Luke
User Blog: luke.com
points: 4
```

I used a code like this but obviously wont work:

```
$sql =
    "SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value" .
    " FROM wp_usermeta" .
    " WHERE meta_key IN ('name','userurl','points')" .
    " ORDER BY meta_value DESC";

$usermeta = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

print("<ul>");
foreach ($usermeta as $post)
{
    print('<li>' . $post->meta_value . '<br/>');
    print('</li><br><br>');
}
print("</ul>");
```

Comment: Both `luke` and `frank` have the same `user_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
     SELECT `user_id`,
     max(case when  `meta_key` = 'name' then `usermeta` end)  as name  ,
     max(case when  `meta_key` = 'userurl' then `usermeta` end) as website ,
     max(case when  `meta_key` = 'points' then `usermeta` end ) as points 
     FROM wp_usermeta
     GROUP BY `user_id`           
     ORDER BY points DESC
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b500a/5)

- you should structure your table like that for better and easier insert and update and select.

  ```
  user_id   name     userurl    points 
    1       mark     mark.com     8
    2       luke     luke.com     4
    3       frank    frank.com    6
  ```

and then do this query

```
   select * from table order by points
```

EDIT:

```
   $usermeta = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error()) ;

 echo"<ul>";
 foreach ($usermeta as $post)
 {
 echo "<li>" . $post->name ." have ".$post->points. " Points </li><br /><br />" ;

 }
 echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: hello thank for reply! it works but show just the points like this: 8 6 4

Comment: @nikz Both luke and frank have the same user_id ? 2 ?

Comment: sorry i did a mistake wrote 2 instead 3 but you got the sense anyway :)

Comment: hello thanks for the code... output is black page... but for sure the code is right as shown on the demo pages....

Comment: Just an other thing... i tryed update mark points with a value of 3 points, but the order is the same 3,6,4 instead 6,4,3

Comment: yes , change order by to this , `ORDER BY points DESC` . i edited it.

Answer (score 1):

you can probably do something like

```
select t1.user_id, t1.meta_value, t2.meta_value, t3.meta_value
from wp_usermeta t1
inner join wp_usermeta t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t2.meta_key = 'userurl'
inner join wp_usermeta t3 on t2.user_id = t3.user_id and t3.meta_key = 'points'
where t1.meta_key = 'name'
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using 2 queries?

First one to get the order by points, the second to get the data?  Then manipulate the data from both results to create a new ordered array?

```
SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'points' ORDER BY meta_value DESC;

SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value WHERE meta_key IN ('name','userurl','points');
```